# ExcelWorksheet Dimension NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception, epplus

So I have this code for a window:

```
public partial class List : Window
{
    DataTable table = null;
    ExcelWorksheet ws = null;
    string user = System.Environment.UserName;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        string path = "Log.xlsx";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    bool sheetfound = false;

                    //runs through each sheet to find a specific one
                    foreach (ExcelWorksheet sheet in pack.Workbook.Worksheets)
                    {
                        if (sheet.Name.Equals(user))
                        {
                            sheetfound = true;
                            ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets[user];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //Creates new sheet if it hasn't found the specific one
                    if (!(sheetfound))
                    {
                        ws = MainWindow.Create_Worksheet(pack);
                        pack.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                        ExcelWorksheet ws = MainWindow.Create_Worksheet(pack);
                        pack.Save();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception caught:\n\n" + ex as string, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        fUpdate(new Object, new RoutedEventArgs);
    }

    public void fUpdate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        table.Rows.Clear();

        MessageBox.Show(ws.Dimension.End.Row.ToString());
    }
}
```

and this one from the main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static ExcelWorksheet Create_Worksheet(ExcelPackage pack)
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(System.Environment.UserName);

        ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Date";
        ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Time";

        ws.View.FreezePanes(2, 1);

        return ws;
    }
}
```

What this is supposed to do right now is, when the second window launches, it sets the Excel file and worksheet. I used Quickwatch to see if it works and it does work, **ws** gets set to the specific sheet that I wanted and `ws.Dimension.End.Row` returns 1. However, after it gets out of the try-catch part (once it reaches fUpdate), `ws.Dimension.End.Row` suddenly throws a NullReferenceException. I checked and ws is still the same ExcelWorksheet object and it didn't go through anything (that I know of) that would change its value. What causes this error? Thanks!

(`ws` returns the ExcelWorksheet object but `ws.Dimensions` return the exception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4):

The `Dimension` object of the `ExcelWorksheet` will be null if the worksheet was just initialized and is empty.

For example:

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = new ExcelPackage().Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Dimension.End.Row);
```

This code will throw a NullReferenceException since the `Dimension` object is null.

On the other hand:

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = new ExcelPackage().Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Some text value";
Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Dimension.End.Row);
```

This code will not throw an exception since the Dimension object was initialized by adding content to the worksheet.

If the loaded `ExcelWorksheet` already contains data, you will not face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may get NullReferenceException if your file doesn't exists. In this case you're getting into `ELSE` block and assigning created WorkSheet to a local method variable instead of class variable.

```
using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    // ExcelWorksheet ws = MainWindow.Create_Worksheet(pack); // wrong
    ws = MainWindow.Create_Worksheet(pack); // right
    pack.Save();
}
```

Comment: I'll keep that as a precaution soon, thanks!

However, I made another system somewhere in the program that creates the file if it doesn't exist already and it does detect that file and go into the `if` block where I actually get what I want

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming along years later like me and facing this issue.  This **also** happens if the ExcelPackage is disposed.

Specifically I had a method where I had

```
using ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi);
return excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
```

This returns a worksheet, but because the ExcelPackage is disposed when the method is exited, the Dimensions property is null (as are many other properties).